# CakePHP Facebook plugin: login fails

Tags: facebook, authentication, cakephp

I am trying to set a Facebook login in my CakePHP-driven site (without complicating myself using the AuthComponent).
I am currently learning from Nick Baker's screencast.

I've set up my `/system32/drivers/etc/hosts/` file, saved the paths in Facebook and set everything up in CakePHP. The problem is that when I click on the Login button and Allow the application, it redirects me back, but with the `$this->Connect->user();` still empty. Cookies are being set for the domain. I have to add that I test locally, therefore the base URL is `local.localdomain` (just like in the screencast).

So what could the problem be? Everything works as expected but the associative array remains empty.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using Webtechnik's Facebook plugin.

Have you made sure that the settings from facebook, App Settings > Web site > site URL and the site domain is correctly set?

Comment: Yes, they are, like in the screencast. Anyway, I went testing on my live server and everything works. But still, I need to know why it didn't on my localhost...

Comment: I had to change those settings everytime I switch testing from local to live server. It may be due to that.

Comment: No, I've left only the local settings on Facebook and tried testing only locally, but with no success.